# ASP.net Design fails to load

Tags: asp.net

I've searched high and low, but never found an answer.
In ASP.net VS 2015 update 1, i cannot make Design load. I'd kind of frezzes up.
Any updates, repairs and anything dosen't help.
MSDN dont give any usefull answers, and i dont know where to look anymore.
It is a new page, so there can not be any errors there?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"      Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont get any errors?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Why would you need the design mode to load? Can't you work using the Source mode where you can write your own aspx/html tags?

Comment: I want to drag and drop items from the toolbox.